# yet another application of "them"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could anyone explain the use of ***them*** in the following song (Deep River Blues):

> Let it rain, let it pour,
>   Let it rain a whole lot more,
>   'Cause I got them deep river blues.

Answer (score 1):

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/them?s=t):

> ***adjective***
>   *Nonstandard.* those: *He don't want them books.*

This appears to be using this definition, since *those* can be susbstituted for *them* in the sentence without loosing any meaning.

> 'Cause I got *those* deep river blues.

Although it's a bit less colorful.

Answer (score 1):

This usage of "them" can give quite an informal tone to a sentence, particularly when used in context with other words/pronunciations that belong to the same register:

You know those thing you were talking about yesterday - could be rephrased in a slangy, but homely, way as: you know them fings wot you were goin' on about yesterday.

[I should add that this sort of English is not generally acceptable in essays, although it is frequently found in spoken British English.]